# enum DataGridComboBoxColumn empty when AutoGenerateColumns = false in WPF/MVVMLight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

Developing a `WPF` app using `MVVLight`.

In my models, I have:

..an `enum` named `AttributeType`:

```
public enum AttributeType
    {
        TypeA = 0,
        TypeB = 1,
    }
```

..an `Attribute` class which exposes a `Type` property of type `AttributeType`:

```
public class Attribute : ObservableObject
{       
    //constructors, other fields etc omitted for brevity

    private AttributeType type;
    public AttributeType Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set 
        { 
            type = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Type);
        }
}
```

..and a `DataSet` class with an `Attributes` property of type `List<Attribute>`:

```
public class DataSet : ObservableObject
{       
    //constructors, other fields etc omitted for brevity

    private ObservableCollection<Attribute> attributes;
    public ObservableCollection<Attribute> Attributes
    {
        get { return attributes; }
        set 
        { 
            attributes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Attributes);
        }
    }
}
```

In my main window, I have a `DataGrid` which is bound to `DataSet.Attributes` and has `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`, as such:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet.Attributes}">
```

Whenever I instantiate the `DataSet` class via my `ViewModel` and populate `DataSet.Attributes` the `DataGrid` correctly displays a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` for `Attribute.Type` with all the possible `AttributeType` enum values.

If, however, I turn `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to set my own columns:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet.Attributes}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="type" Width="*" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

..the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` this time shows nothing. Other columns and their corresponding bindings work fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following steps. It works fine (tested).

**1. Add resource to your data grid (or at a higher level).**

```
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <!--Create list of enumeration values-->
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type Type="local:AttributeType"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

**2. Update the binding of DataGridComboBoxColumn. The static resource is required to resolve the members of enumeration. See the MethodName in step 1 which returns the values of the bound object type.**

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" Width="100"
            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Type}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Update 1**

You will also need to define a local namespace at the Main container level. Replace WpfApplication1 with your namespace path.

```
  xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Comment: i've added the local namespace already, but blend highlights this: `ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">` and gives these two errors: `The namespace prefix 'System' is not defined` and `Enum is not supported in a WPF project`

Comment: @globetrotter check my update. you need do add the system namespace as well.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thanks. If this is the default solution it feels like a bit of an overkill to me. Why does it know how to resolve the members of the `enum` when `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true on the `DataGrid` though? Also, will your solution work fine with `TwoWay` binding?

Comment: i'm marking your post as answer. still confused about the question above though.

Comment: @globetrotter Yes, I tested and changing the values actually changes the model. Regarding enum resolution, we know that when AutoGenerateColumns is set to true the DataGrid autoresolves the Enum members but if AutoGenerateColumns is set to false, ObjectDataProvider is the only solution which seems straight as of date. There are other answers in stackoverflow but they seem quite different from your requirment having implementation with {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor...}. I will be happy to see a better answer.

Comment: thanks for all these useful information. I've encountered a new issue with my `DataGrids` and have posted a new question about it, would appreciate your feedback http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563946/wpf-mvvmlight-update-datagrid-based-on-selecteditem-of-another-datagrid