# WPF MVVMLight: Update DataGrid based on SelectedItem of another DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

Developing a `WPF` app using `MVVMLight`.

My `Model` consists of an `Attribute` class and a `DataSet` class with an `ObservableCollection<Attribute>` property named `Attributes`.

My `MainViewModel` has a `DataSet` property.

In my `MainView` which has it's `DataContext` set to `MainViewModel` I have two `DataGrids`. One has it's `ItemsSource` binded to `DataSet.Attributes` which works fine:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet.Attributes}">
//some DataGrid columns here
```

I want the second `DataGrid` to display some additional properties based on the `SelectedItem` of the first DataGrid, so I did the following:

1) added a `SelectedAttribute` property of type `Attribute` in my `MainViewModel`:

```
private Attribute selectedAttribute;
public Attribute SelectedAttribute
{
    get { return selectedAttribute; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedAttribute == value)
        {
            return;
        }
        selectedAttribute = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedAttribute);
    }
}
```

2) modified my first `DataGrid` to bind it's `SelectedItem` to `SelectedAttribute`:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet.Attributes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAttribute}">
```

3) **Update 1** set the `ItemsSource` of the second `DataGrid` to `SelectedAttribute` and created a column bound to the `Categories` property of `SelectedAttribute` which is an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Main.SelectedAttribute}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Main.SelectedAttribute.Categories}"  />                      
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

4) in my `MainViewModel`, once `DataSet.Attributes` is populated, I set the `SelectedAttribute` to the first `Attribute` in the collection (just as a test):

```
SelectedAttribute = DataSet.Attributes[0];
```

Once I run this, the first `DataGrid` loads fine, but no item is selected and the second `DataGrid` shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SelectedAttribute is a single object, and you are trying to bind it to a data grid which needs a data source that implements IEnumerable.  Try making SelectedAttribute an observable collection and enforce only one item in code.

Comment: hi paul, the column of the second `DataGrid` is actually bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>` property of `Attribute`, see updated post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemsSource of a grid must be IEnumerable.  So this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Main.SelectedAttribute}"
```

will not work because SelectedAttribute is an instance of a class, not some sort of list.

You are also binding something that presumably *does* implement IEnumerable (categories) to a DataTextColumn, which is also wrong; the binding of a grid column must be a scalar property.

EDIT: You're not going to be able to bind thee columns in a grid to three separate observable collections directly; you are going to need to make a new model class to hold the stuff you want to show up in the grid, like:

```
public class SomeGridItem
{
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public string SecondProp {get; set;}
    public string ThirdProp [get; set;}
}
```

Then add a new property on your view model -- this is what you will bind the grid to:

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeGridItem> Blahs {get; set;}
```

Then when the SelectedAttribute changes, you will need to populate Blahs.  You could do this in the property setter for SelectedAttribute (probably easiest), or you could react to SelectedAttribute's PropertyChanged event.  This is pseudocode, but it should give you an idea of what needs to be done.

```
Blah.Clear();

for (var i = 0; i < SelectedAttribute.Categories.Count; i++) {
   Blahs.Add(new SomeGridItem() {
        Category = SelectedAttribute.Categories[i],
        SecondProp = SelectedAttribute.SecondCollection[i],
        ThirdProp = SelectedAttribute.ThirdCollection[i]
    });
}
```

Then bind to your grid.

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Main.Blahs}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Category}"  />                      
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding SecondProp}"  />                      
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding ThirdProp}"  />                      
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: @paul-abbott-wa-us, it's three columns for three `ObservableCollection` properties of `Attribute` (`Categories` & 2 more). This is why I was trying to bind `ItemsSource` to `Main.SelectedAttribute`

Comment: These three observable collections are guaranteed to have the same number of items?  And they are related by position -- as in, the value of Categories[0] corresponds to the value of SecondCollection[0] and ThridCollection[0]?

Comment: @paul-abbott-wa-us yes for both questions

Comment: i think i got it paul thanks, i'll try out your solution. I don't however understand why I'm not able to bind thee columns in a grid to three separate observable collections directly since they're all of same size and related by index. Is there another control which would better suit my needs? i should also note that i'm planning to implement `TwoWay` binding for these properties