# One ObservableCollection per DataGridColumn in WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Developing a `WPF` app using `MVVMLight`.

I'm trying to bind each `DataGridColumn` of a `DataGrid`(with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `False`) to one `ObservableCollection<string>` per column. [I've already asked something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563946/wpf-mvvmlight-update-datagrid-based-on-selecteditem-of-another-datagrid/24564412) and received a very good answer but the problem with that approach is that items get added in the `DataGrid` one row at a time. That approach also introduces a new `Model` class which makes it a problem for `TwoWay` binding with the actual `Model` class I need to keep in sync with my `View`.

My question is this: Assuming that I have several `ObservableCollection<string>` of the exact same count/length, is it possible to bind one `ObservableCollection<string>` per column? My approach so far has been this:

- create an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>` (let's name it `GridColumns`) property on my `ViewModel` containing each `ObservableCollections<string>` I need
- bind the `ItemsSource` of my `DataGrid` to `GridColumns`
- set the binding of each
  `DataGridColumn` to each `ObservableCollection<string>` in `GridColumns`

I can't seem to get it to work though. Am I totally off with this approach?

**EDIT:**

Here is what I came up with:

1) Created a `Model` class which exposes `ObservableCollection` properties

```
 public class AttributeListItems : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> category;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Category
        {
            get { return category; }
            set
            {
                if (category == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                category = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Category);
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<string> fileValue;
        public ObservableCollection<string> FileValue
        {
            get { return fileValue; }
            set
            {
                if (fileValue == value)
                {
                    return;
            }
                fileValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FileValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Created a property of `ObservableCollection<AttributeListItems>` on my `ViewModel`:

```
    private ObservableCollection<AttributeListItems> gridItems;
    public ObservableCollection<AttributeListItems> GridItems
    {
        get { return gridItems;  }
        set
        {
            if (gridItems == value)
            { return; }
            gridItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => GridItems);
        }
    }
```

3) On the `setter` of my `SelectedAttribute` property of my `ViewModel` (which is when I want `GridItems` to be repopulated) I added this:

```
            gridItems.Clear();
            gridItems.Add(new AttributeListItems { 
                Category = selectedAttribute.Categories, 
                FileValue = selectedAttribute.FileValues } 
                );
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => GridItems);
```

4) And on my `View` I set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to `GridItems` and the binding of it's column to `Category`, as such:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Category}" />
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="file values" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding FileValue}" />-->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I run this, the `DataGrid` only shows one row in the column, it's text being `"(Collection)"`. I tried changing the binding of the column from `Category` to `Category/`, which partially works: it only shows the **first** value of the `Category` collection instead of all of them, which is where I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: Do you want to create  or remove columns in your DataGrid on the fly?

Comment: @bit nope as there's no need for that - the columns will contain a finite number of `ObservableCollection<T>` of which all have the exact same length

Comment: So your columns need to be Categories and FileValues?

Comment: @bit in the final result there should be one additional column (ideally a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`) which is bound to `ObservableCollection<bool>`, but since I'm still trying to implement this I didn't include it in the example/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a

```
class RowItem
{
    bool IsChecked;
    string Category;
    string FileValue;
}
```

Then you populate a Collection of `RowItem` s where ever you need it, by something like

```
GridData = new ObservableCollection<RowItem>();
```

And finally in the XAML,

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Checked" Width="auto" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Categories" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Category}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="File values" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding FileValue}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also, it seems like you have `selectedAttribute.Categories` and `selectedAttribute.FileValues` collections as the data source.
Assuming that they have the same length the `GridData` can be populated by:

```
var rowItems = new List<RowItem>();

for( int i = 0; i < selectedAttribute.Categories.Count; i++ )
{
    var row = new RowItem 
    { 
        Category =  selectedAttribute.Categories[i],
        FileValues =  selectedAttribute.FileValues[i],
    };
    rowItems.Add(row);
}

GridData = new ObservableCollection<RowItem>(rowItems);
```

Comment: in your code, it should be `selectedAttribute.Categories[i]`, not `selectedAttribute[i].Categories[i]`. I understand your solution but if you check the link I posted on my post, you will see that a similar answer was given to me on a previous post. My question with such an approach is with `TwoWay` binding: when I change a value of `Category` in the `DataGrid`, (let's say category 9), i also need it to update `selectedAttribute.Categories[9]`

Comment: check out the `TwoWay` binding part of the question in my comment. what happens in such a case?

Comment: You will have the updated values in the GridData collection, so while saving the changes, you will have to device a mechanism to convert the gird data to your required objects back

Comment: yes, any suggestions as to how to pass the updated values back?

Comment: Wouldn't it simply be reversing the convert to GridData loop..?

Comment: hmm, yeah makes sense. i guess the "reverse engineering loop" could go in the `setter` of `GridData` ?

Comment: You should do it under the Save_Click rather

Comment: but I'm going with `MVVM`, trying to eliminate code-behind

Comment: In the SaveCommand then..

Now please ask a new question, if any!

Comment: you're right, thanks! & my apologies for the questions, got carried away ;)